# ReactNative nativo Android com Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, auth

Estou adentrando no mundo do React Native com EXPO, porém estou com algumas dificuldades!

Quem puder, gostaria q me disse os comandos passo a passo de como criar uma aplicação react native com a pasta "android" na raiz junto aos comandos do firebase para Auth e Firestore!

Geralmente quando crio uma aplicação, n vem com a pasta "android", quando ejeto o EXPO a pasta android aparece, porém junto a ela alguns erros vem junto, como n consigo mais executar no emulador.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.